# В IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 неправильно работает ввод вывод программы на perl

Tags: perl

Установил плагин perl в IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3, но следующая программа ничего не печатая сразу ожидает ввода, и только когда его делаешь, выводит все сразу. Вот код:

`#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello, what is you name?\n";
$s = <>;
print 'Hello' . $s;`

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Да, если запускать из cmd, то все работает нормально.

Comment: Где то уже здесь был вопрос, в котором жаловались на подобное, только для плюсового кода и тогда определили, что это просто бага внутри IDE.

Comment: Попробуйте перед print добавить строку `$|=1`; Не знаю поможет или нет но оно заставляет сбрасывать поток вывода при каждой печати.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вроде заработало.

Comment: @Mike ну по-хорошему работать должно и без `$|`.

Comment: @edem Мало ли что должно. но кто же его знает как организован сброс буферов в конкретной запускающей и конролирующей ввод-вывод программе. Раз ТС это помогло, значит глючный там сброс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогам переписки в комментариях стало ясно, что в IDE проблема со сбросом буферов. По хорошему перед вводом чего либо в STDIN весь вывод на консоль в STDOUT должен быть сброшен. В данном случае этого не происходит.

Для принудительного сброса буферов ввода-вывода после каждой операции печати его надо включить в начале программы:

```
$|=1;
```